# Gradle files causing unexpected app crash: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, firebase, android-support-library, androidx

So, I updated my gradle files and my app started crashing with some weird errors. It started crashing out of nowhere and I also go an error, which I didn't have before, on my navigation drawer code in my java class.

I have tried using my version control to get back to how it was, but it still crashes.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.shrinkio"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] } }
buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0"
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.0'
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Process: com.example.shrinkio, PID: 20948
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shrinkio/com.example.shrinkio.Login.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.shrinkio:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.shrinkio:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.shrinkio:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.shrinkio:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.shrinkio:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:815)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:659)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.example.shrinkio.Login.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.shrinkio-kyhW6IGkqM__-vcrljTxwQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.shrinkio-kyhW6IGkqM__-vcrljTxwQ==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
2019-08-28 08:02:42.030 20948-20948/com.example.shrinkio E/AndroidRuntime:     
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        ... 26 more
```

Comment: You should include the complete stack trace of the error, as it usually contains  the actual source of the error.

Comment: Try with `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2`

Comment: if you are using android x then com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3 wont work and error is same about that..

Comment: You should also provide your XML layout.

Comment: You are using [firebase libraries version](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#update_-_june_17_2019) which require androidx migration.

Comment: @ShivamOberoi Which ones are they, should I remove them or migrate do androidx?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti  Thank you for your answer for starters, should I delete the libraries or migrate?

Comment: @TomasMota You should migrate the support libraries to andriodx and the support-design to 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I will do it now and let you know

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I did that and I still get the same error regardless the constraint layout on Main Activity

Comment: migrate your app to androidx and also upgrade your libraries

Comment: @RahulGoswami Thank you for your answer, I already did that but still get the same error, check the error stack trace, i updated it with the full thing

Comment: @TomasMota Check the answer. You are using a wrong package for the ConstraintLayout.

Comment: Post your updated `activity_main`?

Comment: @TomasMota Did it resolve? or there are other issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using [firebase libraries](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#update_-_june_17_2019) which require androidx migration.
[**Migrate**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) to **androidx** library.
Here you can find the [**mappings from old support library** artifacts](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings).
For the **support-design** use the [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases): `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'`

Then **check the package name** of your classes. Your error is:

> Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout
>    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout

**Replace** the xml tag `<androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout>` with the [right class](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout):

```
androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
```

Here you can find the [class mapping](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings).

Comment: Thank you, it solved that error, although whenever the second activity pops ups, which is the login activity with the firebase auth it gives me an error, that the password is invalid (on stack trace) and crashes.

Comment: @TomasMota It seems a separated problem not related to this question.You may wish to consider asking a separate question with detail and stacktrace.